# Remove spaces from a list of integers

Tags: python, list

I wrote a code that accepts multiple numbers and converts them into a list of integers. But I get them with spaces.

For example: I enter as input: 1,2,3,4,5 (**with commas**).

I get a list of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Now I just need to delete the spaces but It's not working, I need it to look something like this `[1,2,3,4,5]`.
I tried doing it this way:

```
numbers = input().split(',')

for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
    numbers[i] = int(numbers[i])
mylist = str(numbers).replace(' ','')
print(mylist)
```

This causes the square parentheses to be considered as items.

How do I delete the spaces the right way?

Comment: When I run your code I get `[1,2,3,4,5]` (i.e. no spaces).

Comment: Your for loop and preceding line could be replaced with: `numbers = [int(i) for in in input().split(',')]` or `numbers = list(map(int, input().split(',')))`

Comment: There *are no spaces in your list*, this is critical to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the print behavior of the list to something you code yourself.

```py
numbers = input().split(',')

for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
    numbers[i] = int(numbers[i])
mylist = str(numbers).replace(' ','')

print('[' + ','.join([str(n) for n in numbers]) + ']')
```

This prints a bracket `[`, then each number separated by commas without any spaces, and finally the ending bracket `]`.

Output looks like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: `join` doesn't require a list comprehension. You could pass in a generator expression: `','.join(str(n) for n in numbers)`. Or even just: `','.join(map(str, numbers))`

Comment: Either one works. I just used list comprehension because it's fast and readable.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are conflating the list and the representation of the list. The *list* itself doesn't have spaces, or even commas, it just has the items (in your case, the numbers). The representation of the list is just that - a way to represent the data inside of it in a normal, standard way. That standard includes commas and spaces.

If you want a new thing that represents the list and its items in the way you are saying, you can do that by making a new string just like that.

```py
str(numbers).replace(' ','')
```

This has two functions in it, chained together. First, we do `str(numbers)` to get a string that is the string-representation of the list. This will be the string `'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'`. Then you `replace` any blank space-bar `' '` with nothing `''`.

Edit:

I think I read your question too quickly and see that you did the exact same as what I have in my code here and said it isn't doing exactly what you want to do. I think the answer here is: no.

As I say in my first paragraph, there is the list and there is the lists representation. The function for the list's representation is a python built-in that can not be trivially overridden. I'm not saying it can't be done, but I don't think you'll get it done without defining some new things.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of your problem is that you want to input a list as a string and want to transform it into a Python list of numbers.

If you input the following string `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then you can split on `,` . Then you need to consider removing the leftmost and rightmost character, that correspond to the brackets:

```
numbers = input()[1:-1].split(', ')

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    numbers[i] = int(numbers[i])

print(numbers)
```

Other options to transform the numbers from strings to integers are the following:

- Python built-in `map` function:

  ```
  numbers = input()[1:-1].split(', ')

  numbers = list(map(int, numbers))

  print(numbers)
  ```
- Python list comprehension:

  ```
  numbers = input()[1:-1].split(', ')

  numbers = [int(n) for n in numbers]

  print(numbers)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

What you might want to do is create a subclass of `list` that has the `repr` implementation you want.  That way you can still operate on your list object as you would any other list (e.g. you can access `numbers[0]` and it will return the first number), but printing the list as a whole will produce the output you're looking for.

```
class MyList(list):
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "[" + ",".join(repr(i) for i in self) + "]"

numbers = MyList(int(n) for n in input().split(","))
print(numbers)
print(numbers[0])
```

Input:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
1
```

Since `MyList` is a `list` subclass, you can construct one from any iterable, including a generator expression (as in the code above) or an existing list, e.g.:

```
>>> n_copy = MyList(numbers)
>>> n_copy
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: And as soon as you make even just a *copy*, the spaces are back :-P

Comment: Nah, just make the copy using the `MyList` constructor.  Or add the one-line implementation of `MyList.copy` to make it return a `MyList`, but that's not germane to OP's use case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `re` module's `split` function to deal with the whitespaces when splitting. Then you just need to join the elements with `','` and embed the whole thing between brackets in the string representation.

```
import re

numbers = re.split(r'\s*,\s*', input())

print(f"[{','.join(numbers)}]")
```